# php preg_replace() change text color of words between * * character

Tags: php, html, preg-replace

I'm trying to change the font color of words within a string ($nota) identified by  * * characters. The words are stored in an XML file. As you see below:

```
<vocabulario id="01">
    <nota>I got *something* for you</nota>
</vocabulario>
<vocabulario id="02">
    <nota>This *gift* is for you</nota>
</vocabulario>
<vocabulario id="01">
    <nota>I got *something* for you</nota>
</vocabulario>
<vocabulario id="03">
    <nota>Nice *ball*</nota>
</vocabulario>
```

The words something, gift, and ball in these strings above are between two `*`s and should be displayed in a different color of the rest of the phrase. At the same time, the `*` characters should be erased/replaced to not display on the page (output).

Result expected: "something", "gift", "ball" should be displayed in red color on the page (output). 
Each new entry stored inside * * characters should be displayed in red color.

Here is my code, but it doesn't work as I expect:

```
<?php

    $new_text = preg_replace('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/', '<span style="color:red;">$1</span>', $nota);


?>
```

Comment: Are you sure your `$words` contains a single `*`? Why `explode` it?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I need some help because I have no idea how to solve this. I'm a newbie. Could you help me, please?

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew $nota

Comment: See https://3v4l.org/SVTHS

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew To be clear: All strings from $nota are stored in an XML file. There are many words and phrases. And inside it are words that are between * * characters to be replaced and change the color of them.

Comment: Please post an [MCVE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I updated my question and code. I think it is easier understand what I mean and want to. Chek it out.

Comment: Then use `$new_text = preg_replace("/\*([^*]+)\*/", "<span style=\"background:#FFFF00;\">$1</span>", $nota )`, see https://3v4l.org/ZRh4n

Comment: I use $new_text = preg_replace("/\*([^*]+)\*/", "<span style=\"background:#FFFF00;\">$1</span>", $nota ), but not happened. The font color didn't change and * still there in the output.

Comment: Then you are not applying the `preg_replace` to the right variable.

Answer (score 1):

I made it! I found the solution. Check it out:

```
<?php
  if (preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/', $nota))// looking for special characters
                 {

    $color = 'red';
    $nota = preg_replace("/\*([^*]+)\*/", "<span style=\"color:".$color.";\">$1</span>", $nota );

}
```

Comment: That is what I suggested, please consider upvoting/accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$path_to_file = 'path/to/the/file';
$file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);
$file_contents = preg_replace("/\*([^*]+)\*/", '<span style="background:#FFFF00;">$1</span>', $file_contents);
file_put_contents($path_to_file,$file_contents);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/ZRh4n) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TTqzks/1).

The `\*` matches a `*` char, `([^*]+)` matches and captures one or more chars other than an asterisk into Group 1 and then a `*` is matched. In the replacement, `$1` refers to Group 1 only, so the `*` on both ends are discarded.